# Как запустить из Python внешний .exe с аргументом

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне нужно запустить из Python программу Steam с аргументами запуска. Я запускал Steam из bat файла таким образом:
start "" "D:\Games\steam\steam.exe"(аргументы запуска например -login)
Можно ли реализовать что то похожее на Python и если да то как?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811691/running-an-outside-program-executable-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конечно, можно: у python в модуле `os` (он сразу встроен в Python) и с помощью команды `os.system(" ")` можно всё вводить как в обычную консоль.

Для вас подходит такой код:

```py
import os

os.system("start путь к файлу аргументы")
```

`os` - это модуль, который позволяет манипулировать командной строкой и работать с файлами. Чаще всего он используеться для манипуляцией с командной строкой (сугубо моё мнение). Подробнее можно почитать [тут](https://pythonworld.ru/moduli/modul-os.html).